# Corona: how to move an image loaded through internet?

Tags: image, sdk, coronasdk

I do not understand what is wrong with this code I get the error:"Attempt to index local 'image' (a nil value)"

```
local image = display.loadRemoteImage( "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LDaA7cP9MmA/Tddgg2e-HcI/AAAAAAAABoQ/xHH5Wau_V00/s1600/hello.png", "GET", networkListener, "helloCopy.png", system.TemporaryDirectory, display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY)
image.x = -100
```

Is there another way to move the image?

Comment: You need to show us the variable tvshowimage. The error states that this value is nil (not correctly set).

Comment: yes sorry the error code is: Attempt to index local 'image' (a nil value)

Comment: That simply means the image was not loaded succesful. And the image variable is still nil.

Answer (score 2):

display.loadRemoteImage() does not return a display object.  This is an asynchronous call.  It returns immediately to your code and when the download completes, your listener function is called.  At that point you have a display object but it's known as  event.target in the listener function.

Once you have it in the listener function you can begin to manipulate it.